# navigationController is always nill

Tags: ios

I am using [this project](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for side menu in my iOS app, and I have **Logoff** as one of menu item. When I click this item I am executing following code snippet.

```
if(varView==4){        
    println("toLogin")
    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if let navController = self.revealViewController().navigationController {
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    else{
        println("There is no vc")
    }
    //if let navController = self.navigationController {
        //navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    //}
    //else{
        //println("There is no vc")
    //}
   //self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)
   //// self.revealViewController().navigationController?.popToViewController(LoginViewController() as UIViewController, animated: true)
   //                        self.revealViewController().navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Always I am getting "There is no vc" as a result. I just want to show **LoginViewController** after **Logoff**.

Comment: Your tutorial is in Objective c and you are using swift

Comment: @Bhumica I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EFfPT3UeWs which explains how to use https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the line `self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)`
then instead of using `navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`, try using `navController.popToRootViewController()`
To look at problem further, what file are you on that github link? There are about 4 different projects he has there.

Comment: Are you saying about `popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`. If yes then same result **There is no vc**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `swift` then follow this tutorial.

It will help you.

[SWrevealview controller in swift](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

and if you are using `objective c`

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;

[revealController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionRight animated:YES];


UIViewController *newFrontController = nil;

newFrontController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newFrontController];

[revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I followed your tutorial, but same result :(

Comment: Then you dont need to write code use simple storyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get you.

Comment: Follow tutorial in that no where your code is used to navigate though it will take to desire page